# Experiential "Have" and "Get"

Tags: experiential-have

I've read in *[Longman English Grammar](http://hcot.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Longman_English_Grammar.pdf)* (PDF, page 258) that we use **get** and **get / have+object+past participle** in a non-causative way for accidents, disasters, etc.  that happen beyond our control.

For  example,

> Don't join in the argument or you might **get** your nose punched.
>
> She **had** her house destroyed in an earthquake.

I think using **have** in non-causative way is to use the **experiential construction** ([Have+object+past participle usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109631/haveobjectpast-participle-usage)).

But here in the first sentence **get** has also been used non-causatively.

Experiential construction shows the experience. So it's called **experiential**. But in the first sentence, the subject (you) hasn't yet experienced of being punched on his nose. But why is this sentence still in **experiential construction**?

Next question:

Do we use **have** and **get** non-causatively in every situation when something happens to us beyond our control?

Comment: They are just passive voice.  "Don't join in the argument or someone might punch your nose.".  "An earthquake destroyed her house."

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting close votes in this question

Comment: @JohnFeltz: Nah -- the passive-voice equivalents would be "your nose might be [*or* get] punched" and "her house was destroyed". The constructions in the OP's examples are distinct. (And although the OP's specific examples at least include passive participles -- creating similarity with the passive voice -- the construction doesn't require that; consider "You might get your nose dirty", with the adjective "dirty", and "She had two close friends move away within a few weeks of each other", with the (active) infinitive "move".)

Answer (score 3):

> But in the first sentence, the subject (you) hasn't yet experienced of being punched on his nose. But why this sentence is still in Experiential construction ?

Because tense is separate from word choice. A sentence like "You will experience happiness" is perfectly fine, and describes an experience you will (I assume) have, even though it doesn't say whether you've already experienced it.

> Do we use have and Get non-causativelx in every situation when something happens to us beyond our control ?

No, not at all. Firstly, there are some other constructions that have the same effect; for example, "My car gave out on me when I was twenty miles outside of town" means the same as "I had my car give out when […]". Secondly, we don't usually bother to indicate the experiencer explicitly; for example, we might just say "Her house was destroyed in an earthquake" and let people infer that this had an effect on her. (Sometimes this results in ambiguity; something like "Michael dropped it on the floor" doesn't specify whether he intentionally dropped it (Michael = agent), vs. whether it fell from his grasp (Michael = experiencer). In many cases it's clear from context; in other cases, it can be better to reword.)