# Have+object+past participle usage

Tags: experiential-have

Source: http://hcot.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Longman_English_Grammar.pdf

page No 258

uses of 'have' + object + past participle

1. In the sense of 'experience

> You should understand by now You've had it explained often
>   enough' (= it has been explained to you)
>
> When he got up to speak the minister had eggs thrown at him

How above sentences shows the **experience** ? These sentences just looks like causative form.

2. To describe the present result of past action

> We now have the problem solved

How this sentence has the present result of past action ? If we remove **now** It will be the causative sentence, won't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are four distinct constructions which employ *HAVE* with a *past participle* and an object. One is the *perfect* construction, which I assume you are familiar with; the others I'll call the *causative*, the *experiential* and the *attained-state* constructions.

Below I use the conventional form *VERBen* for the past participle.

**THE PERFECT CONSTRUCTION**

> I have explained it to you.  –*I performed the explanation.*
>   Demonstrators have thrown eggs at the minister. –*The demonstrators performed the throwing.*

- In this construction, *SUBJECT* is the AGENT of *VERB*, and *OBJECT* typically lies after the past participle.

  > *SUBJECT HAVE VERBen OBJECT*

  In the other three constructions the *OBJECT* of *VERB* lies **between** *HAVE* and *VERBen*, and *SUBJECT* is the *AGENT* only of *HAVE*, not of *VERB*.

  > *SUBJECT HAVE OBJECT VERBen*

**THE CAUSATIVE CONSTRUCTION**

> I will have it explained to you (by my secretary).
>   The opposition had eggs thrown at the minister (by paid demonstrators).

- In this construction, *SUBJECT* is the *AGENT* of *HAVE* in the sense "induce, cause", but the action of *VERBen* is carried out by some other party: *SUBJECT* causes that other party to perform the action. *VERBen* is in effect a passive participle; if the *AGENT* of *VERB* is to be named that must be done with a *by* phrase, exactly as in the passive construction.

**THE EXPERIENTIAL CONSTRUCTION**

> 1a. You've had it explained often enough.

- In this construction, *SUBJECT* undergoes the experience of *OBJECT* being *VERBen*; again, *VERBen* is a passive participle and its action is carried out by some other party. Distinguish this from the *perfect* (it was not you who explained) and from the *causative* (you didn't cause somebody else to explain it) —*You have undergone the experience of its being explained.*

> 1b. The minister had eggs thrown at him.

- Distinguish this from the *perfect* (it was not the minister who threw the eggs) and from the *causative* (the minister didn't incite somebody else to throw eggs at him)—*The minister underwent the experience of eggs being thrown at him.*

**THE ATTAINED-STATE CONSTRUCTION**

> We now have the problem solved.

- Longman's description is I think misleading. In this construction *HAVE* retains its core lexical sense of "hold, possess, receive", and the past participle is basically an adjectival object complement: *We have the problem [and it has been] solved* or *We have the problem [and it is] in a solved state*. *VERBen* is emphatically 'perfective', it names a state which *OBJECT* has attained—which is probably the reason for Longman's description.

  This construction in fact appears to be the oldest of the four constructions, present in both Germanic and Romance languages—even Latin—and it is widely conjectured to be the origin of the perfect construction. Today the attained-state construction is used mostly to introduce the fact of *OBJECT*'s *VERBen* state as a launching point for describing what can be done next: "We have the problem solved, so we can move ahead to ...".

Comment: With all respect, and with interest in and appreciation for the care, thought, and rigor that obviously inform both this answer and the following commentary, I fear there are exactly two chances that the OP will understand it: _Slim_ and _None,_ and _Slim_ is out of town.

Comment: @P.E.Dant We've always had a bunch of really skinny OPs around here (someday when you've got nothing better to do, look up the questions from Listenever and KinzleB) who lust after detailed technical explanations. The beauty of the multi-Answer format is that everybody's free to answer at whatever length and in whatever idiom strikes their fancy--and thus *all* our users, beginners and sophisticates alike, get a satisfying answer. At least that's the theory.

Comment: @P.E.Dant (But there's also a degree of "Je n'ai l'ait celle-ci plus longue que parce que je n'ai pas eu le loisir de la faire plus courte.")

Comment: @StoneyB d'accord. And of course, even at its most concise, the answer would be too long to fit in the margin. :)

Comment: @Stoneyb. Very good answer ! But the so called experiential construction is often confused with Causative construction, both are- Have+object+past participle, How to distinguish ? Next, In "we now have the problem", if we remove "now", it will be causative too.

Comment: @yubrajsharma If you look at my conversation with FumbleFingers in the comments you will see my answer -- "Context, context, context!" ... For instance: simple present *We have the problem solved* will only be used causatively if you are speaking of repeated, habitual problems and solutions: ***Whenever** we encounter such-and-such we have the problem solved by Joe*. If you are speaking of a single solved problem, the default understanding is attained-state.

Comment: I know **I have been explained** . . . isn't experiantial construction but passive present  perfect. But what about my first sentence where I wrote "I have had explained about . . .construction"? It looks like a causative construction. But I want to make it experiential construction

Comment: @yubrajsharma *Explain* can't be passivized with either the recipient of the explanation or the oblique of *about* for subject. You have to say "I've had the passive present construction explained to me"--and I'm afraid there's nothing in the sentence itself to say whether it's experiential or causative.

Comment: @stoneyB can I say that "Construction of both experiential and causative is the same but their meaning differ depending on the context. Without context, using this construction is likely to be ambiguous as it creates ambiguity in their meanings. Encluding the agents(doer) in causative sentences is also a way to dfferentiate it from experiential construction"

Comment: @yubrajsharma That's very well put. But the bit about agency isn't necessarily true - for instance "I had my roof blown away by a tornado" is unlikely to be causative!

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for replying. I think my this question is related to my previous question in http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109607/non-causative-have-and-get?noredirect=1#comment220217_109607 where I had asked about Non-causative get and have, That question is also about experiential construction?

Comment: @yubrajsharma Yes. I hadn't seen that question before, but it's essentially the same matter.